# Using a PHP applied navbar how can I make it appear slightly different on each of my pages?

Tags: php, html, css

I am using the PHP function **ob_start** (output buffering)... to piece together a 'template' containing all the bits which are mostly the same on each page (i.e. Navbar and background colour etc) and the 'content' which is unique to each page.

However for when on a specific page I would like that page's link in the navigation bar to change to a different colour (just to highlight which page you're on), is there a way I can get it to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: Yes, add a different CSS class to the page link in the navigation bar depending on the currently active page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the path and query parameters with which your script was called. And compare it to your page's url, if they match, that's the page you are on.

For example:

```
<style>
a { color: blue; }
a.current { color: orange; }
</style>

<?php

$page1_url = '/path/page.php?subpage=1';
$page2_url = '/path/page.php?subpage=2';
$page3_url = '/path/page.php?subpage=3';


/**
 *
 * determine if link is part of the request uri, and if so assume we are on that page   
 *
 * returns true if we are on that page, false otherwise
 *
 */
function is_current_page ($page_url)
{
    $current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    return (strpos ($current_url, $page_url) !== false);
}


?>
<a href="<?php echo $page1_url; ?>" class="<?php echo (is_current_page ($page1_url) ? 'current' : ''); ?>">Page 1</a>
<a href="<?php echo $page2_url; ?>" class="<?php echo (is_current_page ($page2_url) ? 'current' : ''); ?>">Page 2</a>
<a href="<?php echo $page3_url; ?>" class="<?php echo (is_current_page ($page3_url) ? 'current' : ''); ?>">Page 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class named selected:

```
.selected{
padding:1px;
background-color:#eee;
}
```

and add it to the selected link. To know which link(menu) is active you can always send some extra parameter from the server. One example to do it is. Send a key from the backend, on the base of requested menu.
And each menu element must have some unique key as a class.

on page load:

```
$('.key').addClass('selected');
```

this works for me.

Comment: Ok thank you for that, I have managed to confuse myself somewhat.. I have a class for all navbar elements and each has it's own id in the template.php file. I need to change the characteristics of a particular id in the template.php file from the content.php file. I can kind of understand what you have written I'm just not sure how to integrate it, sorry. :/

Comment: totally fine, you should go ahead with what you can easily integrate. :)